# Thread needs to be run continuously even exception occurs in it

Tags: multithreading

My application uses a thread which should be running continuously. If any exception it should log that exception and should not stop.  currently my code is like below. Can any one help me?

```
void methodname()
{
   try
     {
        while(1)
        executable statements
     }
   catch
     {
       log exception
     }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It needs be something like this:

```
while(1)
{
 try
 {
 }
 catch()
 {
   //log the exception
 } 
 //continue looping
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to try/catch the exceptions inside the loop - right now your code exits the loop when an exception is thrown.